# Sublime Text 3 not working with mingw and C++11

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, mingw, sublimetext

I've setup Sublime Text 3 with mingw by making my own build system:

```
{
    "cmd": "mingw32-make",
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

I then have a `Makefile` in the same directory as the sourcefiles which looks like this:

```
all:
    g++ -c main.cpp
    g++ main.o
    main.exe
```

for a basic project with just 1 file.

Everything works, like I want, a file called `main.exe` is being created in that directory and it is being executed in the Sublime Text Console.

As soon as I add the parameter `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` to enable C++11, something really weird happens. Instead of the `main.exe` a file called `a.exe` is being created. When I change `main.exe` to `a.exe` in the `Makefile`, the program gets executed, but crashes shortly after (`a.exe stopped working`).
And this is what it says in the Sublime Console:

> makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
>
> mingw32-make: *** [all] Error -1073741819
>
> [Finished in 3.5s with exit code 2]
>
> [cmd: mingw32-make]
>
> [dir: F:\Projects old\WIP\Programming\encryption]
>
> [path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;F:\Programs\CMake\bin;F:\mingw\mingw32\bin;F:\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;F:\Programs\CMake\bin]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

PS: In the `mingw32\build-info.txt` it says `gcc version 4.8.4`

PPS: `F:\Projects old\WIP\Programming\encryption` is the path of the C++ project

Comment: dont you need the [`-o` flag to compile your object files into an exe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12046210/3087952)?

Comment: I know, I just have a template, because for SFML I need this style. When changing it to `-o main.exe` I get the same result

Comment: Actually a `main.exe` is being created. I crashes just like `a.exe`, though.

Comment: I also can't google the error code, because google doesn't accept numbers and special characters

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @DiCri I switched to Linux. One of the best decisions of my life

Comment: Also, I am using CMake now